# Direct product of projective modules

Tags: modules, projective-module, free-modules

For any nonempty family like $\{ {M_\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ of  $R$-modules we know that if $\prod_{\alpha \in I} M_\alpha$ is a projective $R$-module,then for all $\alpha \in I$, $\{ {M_\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$  is projective too. Is the converse true? If not give me a counter-example.

Any comments are welcome.

Comment: That's not true if $I$ is infinite; for example, you can take $R={\mathbb Z}$, $I={\mathbb N}$ and $M_\alpha={\mathbb Z}$ for all $\alpha$. However, _if_ the direct product is projective, then so are its factors, because each of them is also a summand.

Comment: Is this preposition is true? Any $\mathbb Z$-module is projective iff free?

Comment: Yes, for $\mathbb Z$ that's true.

Comment: Could you  explain more about second part of your first comment?

Comment: For any $\alpha\in I$ you have $\prod_{\beta\in I} M_\beta \cong M_\alpha\times\prod_{\beta\neq\alpha} M_\beta\cong M_\alpha\oplus\prod_{\beta\neq\alpha} M_\beta$.

Comment: That's useful. Thanks.

Comment: I edited, now the first comment is counter example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A theorem by S. U. Chase states that for a ring $R$ the following conditions are equivalent:

1. $R$ is left perfect and right coherent
2. every product of projective left $R$-modules is projective

It's Theorem 3.3 in S. U. Chase, *Direct products of modules*, Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, **97** (1960), 457–473.

[image]

(“Finitely related” is nowadays more commonly referred to as “finitely presented”.)

So you just need to take a non left perfect ring and you have a counterexample: a suitable direct power of the regular module won't be projective.